# how open new IE 11 window from IE 8 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, shell, internet-explorer, browser

I am able to open a new Chrome, Safari, Firefox window from IE 8 but I can't find how do the same to open IE11. Naturally, I know how to open a new IE 8 window from IE 8 and how open new IE 11 from IE 11. Neverthelles, I want to open **11** from **8**.

I added below the code I am using to open Chrome/Safari/Firefox from IE 8 and the tentative to do similiar action to open IE 11.

So my straight question could be how use shell.run or any other approach from javascript to open a new Internet Explorer 11 window from Internet Explorer 8?

Please, before saying that it is a duplicated question, read the one you have in mind if there is really an answer accepted on it and note that I have succesfully done from IE 8 to other no Microsoft browser. Addtionally, don't provide your recomendation to make the application match all Browsers since it is beyond the scope of this question neither tell me to add any plugin to change any configuration in client computer like some register variable or another workaround that depends on I change something in client configuration.

Well, maybe tell me that isn't possible might be the final answer to my question. I read few people answering the question "can I open a different browser ..." that is it impossible but note I am able to do it successfully for at least 3 different browsers.

The code below was based on [Asp Net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1652038.aspx?How%20can%20we%20force%20a%20link%20to%20open%20a%20URL%20in%20a%20different%20browser%20)

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Open Window in different browser</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function openFirefoxURL()

  {

      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

      shell.run("Firefox https://www.google.com/#safe=strict&q=brazil");

  }

  function openSafariURL()

  {

      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

                  shell.run("Safari https://www.google.com/#safe=strict&q=brazil");

  }

  function openChromeURL()

  {

      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

                  shell.run("Chrome https://www.google.com/#safe=strict&q=brazil");

  }

    function openIE11URL()

  {

      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

                  shell.run("iexplore http://www.google.com");

  }

  </script>

</head>

<body>





<input type="button" onclick="openFirefoxURL()" value="Open Google in Firefox"> <!-- working -->

<input type="button" onclick="openSafariURL()" value="Open Google in Safari"> <!-- working -->

<input type="button" onclick="openChromeURL()" value="Open Google in Chrome"> <!-- working -->

<input type="button" onclick="openIEURL()" value="Open Google in IE 11"> <!-- NOT working -->



<a href="javascript:exec('C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe', '-nomerge http://www.google.com');">ie 11</a>  <!-- NOT working -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Future readers may find interesting to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153841/activexobject-creation-error-automation-server-cant-create-object as well. Btw, I must find someway to open IE11 from IE8 and I am looking carefully such thread I opened yesterday.